# How would you modify the muting technique when finger picking on an electric guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

After watching this I was wondering how you would modify the classical guitar technique if you want to fingerpick on the electric guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important is to mute the low strings while playing melody on the high ones. This is by far best done with the thumb of the picking hand. When playing on the A-string, I have it standing upright on the E-string; when playing on the D-string, upright on the A-string but also touching the E-string; when playing on the treble strings, the thumb lies flat across the bass strings. The picking fingers themselves are on the bass strings in an almost perpendicular position (the same I also use when playing electric bass, which basically corresponds to a Flamenco picado), on the treble strings more angled as in normal classical guitar. The thumb only slightly reduces mobility.

On guitar, the top strings don't necessarily need to be muted when playing on lower strings. On bass, this is crucial though, and I do it by at least temporarily lowering the hand down so the index touches all strings in a pressureless barree. On guitar, I only damp a string once when playing a descending line and switching to the next lower string, I use the ring finger and pinky of the picking hand for this.